# Convert seconds to formatted time like 12:59?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsdate, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert seconds to days, minutes, and hours in Obj-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572049/convert-seconds-to-days-minutes-and-hours-in-obj-c)

How to do it in Objective-C

For example:
349200 seconds??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572049/convert-seconds-to-days-minutes-and-hours-in-obj-c

Comment: This is a very similar example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046991/formatting-seconds-into-hhiiss

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the below function and pass "seconds" value in this function.

```
- (void)displayTimeWithSecond:(NSInteger)seconds   
        {  
        NSInteger remindMinute = seconds / 60;
NSInteger remindHours = remindMinute / 60;

NSInteger remindMinutes = seconds - (remindHours * 3600);
NSInteger remindMinuteNew = remindMinutes / 60;

NSInteger remindSecond = seconds - (remindMinuteNew * 60) - (remindHours * 3600);

NSLog(@"Hours = %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",remindHours]);
NSLog(@"Minute = %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",remindMinuteNew]);
NSLog(@"Seconds = %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",remindSecond]); 
}
```

Here, displayTime is Label.

Comment: Hi, Now review functions. It will give Hours, Minutes & Seconds. Cheers.