# Convert seconds into minutes and seconds

Tags: objective-c, time

How can I convert seconds into minutes and seconds?

I am aware that you can convert seconds to minutes like so, but I don't know how I can get the remainder of seconds...

```
int minutes = seconds / 60;
```

Comment: int remainderSeconds = seconds % 60;

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: Post that as an answer, since it is the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert seconds to days, minutes, and hours in Obj-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572049/convert-seconds-to-days-minutes-and-hours-in-obj-c)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You will obtain minutes with :

```
int minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
```

and remaining seconds with:

```
int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;.
```

Comment: Of course, % is the modulo operator, which give the remainder of division of one number by another. So 62 / 60 = 1, and 62 % 60 = 2, since 62 = 1 * 60 + 2

Comment: I was first thinking of giving an example based on 61, but I changed my mind.

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",min,sec]; Result>> 03:21

Comment: damn, so easy...! :)

Answer (score 28):

Here's a better answer from [Convert Seconds Integer To HH:MM, iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739383/convert-seconds-integer-to-hhmm-iphone)

```
- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(int)totalSeconds{

  int seconds = totalSeconds % 60; 
  int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60; 
  int hours = totalSeconds / 3600; 

  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds]; 
}
```

**Swift version:**

```
private func getFormattedVideoTime(totalVideoDuration: Int) -> (hour: Int, minute: Int, seconds: Int){
        let seconds = totalVideoDuration % 60
        let minutes = (totalVideoDuration / 60) % 60
        let hours   = totalVideoDuration / 3600
        return (hours,minutes,seconds)
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Swift

```
/** Returns the seconds as in clock format 02:24  */
    class func formatMinuteSeconds(_ totalSeconds: Int) -> String {

        let minutes = Double(totalSeconds) / 60;
        let seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

        return String(format:"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can resolve this problem with `NSMeasurement` and `NSUnitDuration`. These classes require iOS 10.0+, tvOS 10.0+, macOS 10.12+ or watchOS 3.0+. The code below converts seconds to minutes and seconds.

```
int seconds = 230;
NSMeasurement* measurement = [[NSMeasurement alloc] initWithDoubleValue:seconds unit:NSUnitDuration.seconds];
NSMeasurement* measurementMinutes = [measurement measurementByConvertingToUnit:NSUnitDuration.minutes];
int minutes = floor(measurementMinutes.doubleValue);
NSMeasurement* measurementMinutesWithoutSeconds = [measurement measurementBySubtractingMeasurement:[[NSMeasurement alloc] initWithDoubleValue:minutes unit:NSUnitDuration.minutes]];
int secondsRemainder = floor([measurementMinutesWithoutSeconds measurementByConvertingToUnit:NSUnitDuration.seconds].doubleValue);
NSLog(@"%d %d", minutes, secondsRemainder); // 3 50
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5:**

> String with format hh:mm:ss

```
extension Float {

    var hoursMinutesSecondsFormat : String {
    let seconds = self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
    let minutes = (self / 60).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
    let hours   = (self / 3600).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
    return String(format:"%02.f:%02.f:%02.f", hours,minutes, seconds);
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DateComponentsFormatter: A formatter that creates string representations,
by using unitsStyle u can get a string as you want and mention allowedUnits.
e.g: output for unitsStyle:: for 10000 secods

1. full = "2 hours, 46 minutes, 49 seconds"
2. positional = "2:46:40"
3. abbreviated = "2h 46m 40s"
4. spellOut =  "two hours, forty-six minutes, forty seconds”
5. short = "2hr,46 min,40 sec"
6. brief = "2hr 46min 40sec"

   Easy to use:

   ```
    let time = convertSecondsToHrMinuteSec(seconds: 10000)

    func convertSecondsToHrMinuteSec(seconds:Double) -> String{
            let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
            formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
            formatter.unitsStyle = .full

            let formattedString = formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(seconds))!
            print(formattedString)
            return formattedString
        }
   ```