# how to track that how much time user spent on a screen Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use Google Analytics in my iOS app. I have tracked the events and screens. I want to track the time user spent on specific screens. How I can achieve this?

Comment: Log a screen view when you log the next screen view Google analytics automatically figures out the time on the first screen by when it gets the hit for the second screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it comes to Google Analytics I like to be creative. Here's my possible solution:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
 _startingTime = [NSDate date];
```

---

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 _endingTime = [NSDate date];
 NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [_startingTime timeIntervalSinceDate:_endingTime];
 NSInteger minutesBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / 60;
```

---

Then, you might use [Screens](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/screens) to send the data to your reports.

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[tracker set:kGAIScreenName
       value:@"Home Screen %d", minutesBetweenDates];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
```

---

For more precision on the time interval you might be interested in [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542215/1672895).

Alternatively, you may use [Events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/events) to achieve the same objective.