# how to convert seconds into minutes in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I want to know how to convert seconds to minutes and days according to the URL am getting via web-service-

[image]

I have to use those seconds as to display user's last activity-

[image]

how can I do that???

Comment: can't you do seconds / 60 ?

Comment: That would be `seconds / 60` for integer minutes, or `seconds / 60.0` to include fractional minutes.

Comment: Take a look at `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert seconds into minutes and seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637260/convert-seconds-into-minutes-and-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to get total hour,minutes and seconds for my audio or video player to display duration of it. Method is like,

```
 - (NSString *)timeFormatted:(int)totalSeconds
{

int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;

NSString *finalString;

if (hours > 0) {

    finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds];

}

else{


    finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];

}

return finalString;
}
```

you can make method something like this.

hint :

You can get days something like,

```
 int days = totalSeconds / 86400;
```

Comment: You can display that final string as your label's text, for exa, `yourLabel.text = finalString`. For that you have to call this function like `NSString *finalString = [self timeFormatted:45000];`